# Good math textbook on the intersection of linear algebra and probability

Tags: probability, references, linear, linear-algebra

I've been puzzling over some linear algebra problems and going through some old textbooks, but they rarely talk about prob stats things like expected value, std, or mean.

Is there a good textbook / set of notes which looks at linear algebra from a probability / statistics perspective? For example, with linear algebra you can project a vector orthogonally to a subspace given its basis, but I want to understand about what to do when you have incomplete information.

Comment: hmm not exactly what you're asking for but books on Linear Models Theory may have some relevant stuff.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://www.probabilistic-numerics.org/textbooks/

Comment: Thanks @user5292 .. That might be the way to go, though I was hoping for something less ML and more about just linear algebra and prob/stats.

Comment: And ideally something basic :)

Comment: Some promising leads are available via search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5breferences%5d%20linear%20algebra%20probability%20answers%3a1

Comment: Any rigorous linear model or multivariate analysis textbook should contain abundant intersection of linear algebra and probability/statistics. An illuminating and delightful example is Wichura's *The Coordinate-Free Approach to Linear Models*.  Other classic texts (with ascending math difficulty) include Graybill's *Matrices Applications in Statistics*, Muirhead's *Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory*, Eaton's *Multivariate Statistics:  A Vector Space Approach*.

Comment: Many thanks @Zhanxiong Wichura's textbook looks great.